# iOS: Tableview's footerview bounces on Scroll

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have added a reasonably large button (to hold a clickable image as background) in a table view's footer view. I also intend to add another button below the image.  It became impossible to view the bottom of the image without bouncing back while scrolling to the end of the view.

I looked up the problem and many mentioned that it is caused by the size of the table view being larger than the screen and recommended to minimize it using interface builder. However, It becomes impossible to do so given the size of the image.

Is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement the UITableViewDelegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

and return a height large enough to fit your button.

Answer (score 0):

When the size of the footer view changes, you need to re-assign it to the `tableFooterView` property of your table in order for it to recognize the change.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted; it is a solution to a problem I have run into in the past which I believe will be useful to others.